# Returning promise from a promise handler

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have two functions which are async and returning promises, output of first one has to be fed to the second one and this has to be wrapped in a third function. The caller module calls the third function and doesnt have to know that there are 2 functions internally. The caller code is able to catch all rejections but it doesnt print the resolved value.

What is wrong in the code?

```js
function firstfn(x) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (x === 0)
      reject(new Error("not a valid num"));
    else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("successfully resolving1");
        resolve(x * 2);
      }, 500);
    }

  });
}

function secondfn(y) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (y === 100) reject(new Error("reject from 2"));
    else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("successfully resolving2");
        resolve(y + 2);
      }, 500);
    }

  });
}

function getsecondfn(y) {
  firstfn(y)
    .then(function(response) {
      return secondfn(response);
    })
}

function caller(inp) {
  getsecondfn(inp)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

caller(2);
```

The above code doesnt print 6 but correctly rejects when value is either 0 or 50.

Comment: In `caller()`, change `getsecondfn(inp)` to `return getsecondfn(inp)`.  In `getsecondfn()` change `firstfn(y)` to `return firstfn(y)`.  You have to return promises from your functions for the caller to be able to use them.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by `getsecondfn` since you didn't return a `Promise` in it (means `then` block at `caller` function won't trigger).

Refer below fixed demo:

```js
function firstfn(x) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (x === 0)
      reject(new Error("not a valid num"));
    else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("successfully resolving1");
        resolve(x * 2);
      }, 500);
    }

  });
}

function secondfn(y) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (y === 100) reject(new Error("reject from 2"));
    else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("successfully resolving2");
        resolve(y + 2);
      }, 500);
    }

  });
}

function getsecondfn(y) {
  return firstfn(y)
    .then(function(response) {
      return secondfn(response);
    });
}

function caller(inp) {
  getsecondfn(inp)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

caller(2);
```

Comment: Thanks @Pengyy. Do I need to add catch in getsecondfn or the caller will catch all the errors in its catch block ?

Comment: @ams no need, the outer one can handle all of this.